# Using html5 canvas as a background, how to position a youtube embed on top of it using css to be resolution independent?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, youtube

I am having some issues placing an embedded youtube video on top of an html5 canvas.

You can see an example of my issue at [eternalminerals.com](http://eternalminerals.com) , where I am trying to using the matrix canvas as the background with the Youtube video ontop

On certain computers, it looks fine, but I guess on other resolutions the video get's shifted.

I am simply using

```
element.style {
  position: relative;
  top: -800px;
}
```

on the embeded youtube, but is there a better way so that it would be resolution independent?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
positition : absolute;
```

then set it you wherever you want it to be. That should work.

Then add this:

```
element.style{
 position:absolute; 
left:0;
 right:0;
 margin-left:auto; 
margin-right:auto
; }
```

Comment: if I use position : absolute;, the <center> no longer works, and if I use left: 350px; it doesn't remain in the center when i resize the browser, is there a way to maintain the center positioning while also using position: absolute? It's not centering even though it is between <center></center> tags

Comment: Don't use center tags, rather make the css style to center. Will edit my answer on how to do that.

Comment: `element.style{ position:absolute; left:0; right:0; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; }`

Comment: Thank you so much, Manu!!! This is exactly what I was looking for!!! I learned a lot about the <center> tags too!